# Using custom sections in external app.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, app-config

I've been trying around with my App.config for a while now and am now at the point that I managed to set an external one as my config file and I am able to read/write the appSettings section of this file. Now I could just use different names for the keys of the other section, but I'd like it more to use another section. ConfigurationManager.getSection() seems not to be working, I get a "ConfigurationErrorsException".

My code:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = path + "app.config";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

// Reading:
string value = config.AppSettings.Settings["key"].Value

// Writing:
var settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;
if (settings["key"] == null)
    settings.Add("key", "value");
else
    settings["key"].Value = "value";
```

I tried

```
var settings = config.Sections["section"];
string value = settings["key"];
```

but that doesn't work because of the "degree of protection".
Any ideas on how to do that?

UPDATE:

Solved it! Just used

```
type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection"
```

in the app.config and to get/set the values:

```
var settings = ((AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection(section)).Settings;
```

Comment: What does the `Message` or `InnerException` of the `ConfigurationErrorsException` tell you?

Comment: @mariocatch Just noticed, I also set `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "pathtoconfig")`; the InnerException says "Unknown configuration section: 'infos'", although "infos" exists in the app.config

Comment: Did you declare the `<configSections>` at the top of that config file? With a `<section>` reference to the type you're trying to create a config value for? Here's the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903350(v=vs.71).aspx) for how that is expected to be laid out.

Comment: @mariocatch Thanks, didn't know you had to do this. But now the next problem: What `SectionHandler` should I use in the type attribute? And how do I save it to the file? Tried different Handlers together with `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection()`, but this seems not to be working...